# SSH keys forwarding via Python sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666600/ssh-key-forwarding-using-python-paramiko), but uses `sshtunnel` library instead of directly calling `paramariko`.

Basically, I want to programmatically repeat scenario described [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) (in *Public Key Access with Agent Forwarding* section). The idea is that I have a backend running on **server1** (see aforementioned section, it has graphical scheme). This backend needs to connect **server2** to retrieve some data using my authentication key.

I used to use username/password, and now switched to public keys. When I've used plain password, it was like this:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

APP_CONFIG = {}  # here should be connection configuration

def build_ssh_tunnel_config(app_config):
    cfg = app_config
    return {
        'ssh_address_or_host': (cfg['SSH_TUNNEL_HOST'],
                                int(cfg['SSH_TUNNEL_PORT'])),
        'ssh_password': cfg['SSH_TUNNEL_PASSWORD'],
        'ssh_username': cfg['SSH_TUNNEL_USERNAME'],
        'remote_bind_address': (cfg['SSH_TUNNEL_BIND_HOST'],
                                int(cfg['SSH_TUNNEL_BIND_PORT']))}


cfg = build_ssh_tunnel_config(APP_CONFIG)
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(**cfg)
server.start()
# communicate with host
```

But which classes/parameters should I use to repeat the same process without explicit usage of username/password, using key forwarding instead?

I know how to do it "manually", via terminal, i.e. key forwarding is enabled and works as expected.

#### Update

Here is how I do it when connecting from my **homepc** to **server2** via **server1**:

```
SSH_TUNNEL_CONFIG = {
    'ssh_address_or_host': (server1_address, server1_port),
    'remote_bind_address': (server2_address, server2_port),
    'ssh_pkey': pkey_path
    'ssh_private_key_password': os.environ.get('tunnel_password'),
    'ssh_username': username
}
```

But I don't have a `pkey_path` file on my **server1** host and don't want to store my private key there. That's why key forwarding is needed.

I am not too experienced in SSH configuration, therefore probably doing something wrong or not as simple as it could be.